# Documentation for USPTO Bulk data Applications "Red-book" XMLv4 and XMLv1

Tags: uspto, bulk-download, xml

Does anyone know where to find or have a pdf copy of the documentation for USPTO application XMLv4 and XMLv1 bulk data?  I can only find documentation for USPTO grants XMLv4, XMLv2 and APS.

Here is an link to what I have for grants, but would like the equivalent for applications:

Grants APS Description - https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/grant/redbook/fulltext/1976/PatentFullTextAPSDoc_GreenBook.pdf

Grants XMLv Description - https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/products/PatentGrantSGMLv19-Documentation.pdf

Grants XMLv4 Description - https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/products/PatentGrantXMLv42-Documentation.pdf